# Silverstripe convertDataObjectSet not working

Tags: silverstripe

I have the following code:

```
$data = DataObject::get('Property',"SoftDelete=0 AND Bedrooms >= ".$minBeds." AND Price<='". $maxPrice."'","Price ASC");
$f1 = new JSONDataFormatter(); 
return $f1->convertDataObjectSet($data);
```

However the response is:

```
{"totalSize":null,"items":[]}
```

There are definitely records in the DataObject, as if I do:

```
$data = DataObject::get('Property',"SoftDelete=0 AND Bedrooms >= ".$minBeds." AND Price<='". $maxPrice."'","Price ASC");
foreach($data as $dataobj){
print_r($data);
}
```

I can see the data for all the records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ORM doesn't actually execute a query until it is iterated which explains why results exist when looping over `$data` with foreach but not by just writing the `get(...)` statement.

A solution is to use the `toArray()` method on your DataList which will then execute the query and you'll have the results in an Array:

```
$data = DataObject::get('Property',"SoftDelete=0 AND Bedrooms >= ".$minBeds." AND Price<='". $maxPrice."'","Price ASC")->toArray();
```

(Note that this might/will throw an error is there is no results, so might need to check with `->count()` first)

`convertDataObjectSet()` seems to take an `SS_List` as param, so you might have to convert `$data` (not sure) like so `$data = ArrayList::create( $data )`.

Comment: well got the same nullish response but it was about permission. add appropriate canView function like

 public function canView($member = null) {
  return true; 
 }